# how to realize screen capture with 50fps on android?

Tags: android, screen-capture

how to realize screen capture with 50fps on android? I have tried 'mediaProjection' with almost 5fps and 'minicap' with 10fps.

Comment: what's the expected output format? I have experience on minicap. The JPEG output is around 400k per frame captured without scaling down. For a 50fps capturing, the throughput is 20MB/s. I am not sure whether your device could handle it, but I think a video capturing is more suitable  than screen capturing for your requirement